# How to fix eslint error no-use-before-define

Tags: javascript, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

I am using Airbnb's style guide and have a couple of functions that reference each other this error is triggered no matter which function is above the other.  Is there a best practice on how to fix this error besides just disable it?

```
function foo() {
    const ham = document.querySelector('#ham');
    ham.onclick = () => {
        bar();
    };
}

function bar() {
    const spam = document.querySelector('#spam');
    spam.onclick = () => {
        foo();
    };
}
```

Comment: what framework?

Comment: Vanilla javascript

Comment: try to use eslint config file, there you can stop this error

Comment: I know that I can disable it in the eslint config file, however I wanted to solve the issue it is warning me about rather than just disable it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have to just disable for the first function since your use case is also popular:

```
function foo() {
    const ham = document.querySelector('#ham');
    ham.onclick = () => {
        /* eslint-disable no-use-before-define */
        bar();
    };
}
```

Or you can wrap them up in an literal object to resolve the issue:

```js
const wrapper = {
  foo() {
    const ham = document.querySelector<HTMLDivElement>('#ham');
    ham.onclick = () => {
        wrapper.bar();
    };
  },

  bar() {
    const spam = document.querySelector<HTMLDivElement>('#spam');
    spam.onclick = () => {
        wrapper.foo();
    };
  }
};
```

Comment: I was afraid of that.  I was wondering if there was a way to fix this without just strait up disabling....

Comment: I dropped another idea in the answer as well. Hopefully it would work for you

Comment: Thanks!  I like that answer, very tidy.